How to merge multiple files correctly in python?
My problem is that in my newly created file the data is a mess. Therefore I want to ask what I did wrong in my code. It should look like this:
737224975,69450.10000000,0.00002000,1.38900200,1716854400003,False,True
737224976,69450.10000000,0.00010000,6.94501000,1716854400003,False,True
737224977,69450.10000000,0.00010000,6.94501000,1716854400003,False,True

But for some reason it looks like this:
735704412,69065.44000000,0.00291000,200.98043040,1716819665729,False,True,737224975,69450.10000000,0.00002000,1.38900200,1716854400003
735704413.0,69065.47,0.02,1381.3094,1716819665839.0,True,True,,,,,
735704414.0,69065.46,0.0001,6.906546,1716819665839.0,True,True,,,,,
735704415.0,69065.46,0.03294,2275.0162524,1716819665839.0,True,True,,,,,
735704416.0,69065.44,0.07247,5005.1724368,1716819665839.0,True,True,,,,,
735704417.0,69065.42,0.0001,6.906542,1716819665839.0,True,True,,,,,
735704418.0,69065.24,0.0001,6.906524,1716819665839.0,True,True,,,,,
735704419.0,69064.68,0.02,1381.2936,1716819665844.0,True,True,,,,,
735704420.0,69064.68,0.02588,1787.3939184,1716819665844.0,True,True,,,,,
735704421.0,69064.55,0.0001,6.906455,1716819665844.0,True,True,,,,,
,,,,,False,True,737224976.0,69450.1,0.0001,6.94501,1716854400003.0

This is my python file, which sorts my files after their date and then merges those in sequence and creates a new file:
import os
import re
import pandas as pd

# Define the directory where your CSV files are located
current_directory = os.getcwd()
print(current_directory)

# Construct the path to the "data" folder in the parent directory
directory = os.path.join(current_directory, "static\data")
print(directory)

# Define the naming scheme pattern
pattern = re.compile(r'BTCFDUSD-trades-(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).csv')

# Function to extract date from filename
def extract_date(filename):
    match = pattern.search(filename)
    if match:
        return match.group(1)
    else:
        return None

# Get list of CSV files in the directory
csv_files = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if f.endswith('.csv')]

# Sort the files based on date
csv_files_sorted = sorted(csv_files, key=lambda x: extract_date(x))

# Process the files in sorted order
for filename in csv_files_sorted:
    # Your processing logic goes here, for example:
    # with open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'r') as file:
    #     data = file.read()
    print(filename)

# Check if there are any files to process
if not csv_files_sorted:
    print("No CSV files found to process.")
else:
    # Read and concatenate the CSV files in sorted order
    merged_data = pd.DataFrame()
    for filename in csv_files_sorted:
        file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        merged_data = pd.concat([merged_data, df], ignore_index=True)

    # Extract the first and last date for the new file name
    first_date = extract_date(csv_files_sorted[0])
    last_date = extract_date(csv_files_sorted[-1])
    
    # Define the new filename
    new_filename = f"BTCFDUSD-trades_{first_date}_to_{last_date}.csv"
    new_file_path = os.path.join(directory, new_filename)
    
    # Save the merged dataframe to the new CSV file
    merged_data.to_csv(new_file_path, index=False)
    
    print(f"Merged file saved as: {new_file_path}")

Changing the method of merging meaning concat() and append().

No, they are inconsistent because of the data received. Is it still possible to do, but not to look at the columns but at the lines of the file?

It's possible. Try something like this?

what do you have in files? If they have the same structure then you could use standard open() read() write() to join CSV.

Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I added outfile.write("\n") after
for line in infile:
outfile.write(line)
because the End and Start line of the two file would be merged into one, instead of being seperated.

Do these CSV files have a column header line? It appears that they don't. but read_csv will try to make the first row into a column header. Try read_csv with header=None to see if that sorts things out.

As an aside, (1) you don't need the lambda when sorting because its only 1 unmodified parameter. Do sorted(csv_files, key=extract_date) instead. (2) put all of the dataframes in a list and concat once at the end. Each concat is a copy and that gets expensive.

Just ignore all the Python for a moment. If you were to process the sample input file manually, how would you rearrange it into the desired output format?
